# Find hometown with most students for each class

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables, `Class`, `Student`, `StudentClassInfo`. Their relationship is shown as follows.
[image: ER Diagram]

I want to find the following result.

```
ClassID | ClassName | MostPopularHometown
   c01      CS101          NY
   c02      CS102          LA
   c02      CS102          CA
```

For each Class, I want to find the hometown of the majority of students in that class. For example, if there are 10 students from NY in c01 and students from any other single state is less than 10, then we have a row of `c01      CS101          NY`.
If there are ties, print all of them like the last two rows in the example.

My progress: For each class, I can group students by their hometown. Like following.

```
select dbo.Class.ClassID, max(ClassName) as ClassName, Hometown, count(dbo.Student.StudentID) as NumOfStudents
from dbo.Student inner join dbo.ClassStudentInfo 
on dbo.Student.StudentID=dbo.ClassStudentInfo.StudentID
inner join dbo.Class
on dbo.Class.ClassID=dbo.ClassStudentInfo.ClassID
group by dbo.Class.ClassID, Hometown
order by dbo.Class.ClassID ASC, NumOfStudents DESC
```

The output is like,

[image]
I would like the result to have row 1,2, 3, 5,6,7,8.

Comment: This sounds like an assignment?

Comment: @AndyM It is an exercise from a video course. I am not a student. I am self learning SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [RANK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to assign a rank to each row, based on your partitioning.  Sadly enough, you can't use windowed functions in a where clause, so you'll have to use in a subquery. Then you can select from that and filter on your ranked column.

So, based on your query:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
select
dbo.Class.ClassID,
max(ClassName) as ClassName,
Hometown,
count(dbo.Student.StudentID) as NumOfStudents,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.Class.ClassID order by count(dbo.Student.StudentID) DESC) as Ranked
from dbo.Student
inner join dbo.ClassStudentInfo on dbo.Student.StudentID=dbo.ClassStudentInfo.StudentID
inner join dbo.Class on dbo.Class.ClassID=dbo.ClassStudentInfo.ClassID
group by dbo.Class.ClassID, Hometown
) T
where 
t.ranked = 1
```